# If a Muggle is to turn into a werewolf, would they be able to learn magic?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-creatures, werewolf, muggles

I'm pretty sure that werewolves are magical creatures and, by extension, have magic in them. So, if a Muggle was to get bitten by a werewolf and survive to become a werewolf, would they be able to learn magic or at least have the ability to see other magical creatures such as Dementors?

Comment: Something keeps the werewolf population from growing exponentially, so it could be that a person needs to have magic to survive the infection, and that muggle victims just die from the mauling.

Comment: How do we know muggles can become warewolves in Harry Potter?

Comment: Wouldn't the mere fact of _being_ a werewolf and turning into a wolf monthly, be magical in and of itself? Sure, the muggle may not be able to learn to cast spells, but I'd think the transfiguration itself is reasonably magical.

Answer (score 11):

## No, there’s no mention of Muggle werewolves gaining magic.

Though it is possible for Muggles to become werewolves, there’s no mention of them gaining magical abilities when they do, nor is it mentioned that they become more sensitive to magic.

> “Once a month, at the full moon, the otherwise sane and normal wizard or Muggle afflicted transforms into a murderous beast.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

Most Muggles who are bitten by werewolves end up dying anyway, so there are comparatively few werewolves that are Muggles - most people who survive a werewolf bite are wizards.

> In the late nineteenth century the great English authority on werewolves, Professor Marlowe Forfang, undertook the first comprehensive study of their habits. He found that nearly all those he managed to study and question had been wizards before being bitten. He also learned from the werewolves that Muggles ‘taste’ different to wizards and that they are much more likely to die of their wounds, whereas witches and wizards survive to become werewolves. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Werewolves (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves)*</sup></sub>

There aren’t many Muggle werewolves, but there are some, so if they did gain magical abilities, it’s likely this would have been mentioned or recorded with the other information on werewolves.

Comment: Is Fenrir a muggle werewolf? We never see him using a wand & voldemort doesn't honour him with the dark mark either. Any information about that available?

Comment: @user13267 He Apparates. *“Grab hold, and make it tight. I’ll do Potter!’ said Greyback, seizing a fistful of Harry’s hair; Harry could feel his long, yellow nails scratching his scalp. ‘On three! One – two – three –’ They Disapparated, pulling the prisoners with them. Harry struggled, trying to throw off Greyback’s hand, but it was hopeless: Ron and Hermione were squeezed tightly against him on either side, he could not separate from the group, and as the breath was squeezed out of him his scar seared more painfully still –”* - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23 (Malfoy Manor)*

Answer (score 7):

## Muggles usually die.

Here's a Pottermore quote I found on it:

> He also learned from the werewolves that Muggles ‘taste’ different to wizards and that they are much more likely to die of their wounds, whereas witches and wizards survive to become werewolves.
> <sub><sup>*- [Werewolves - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves)*</sup></sub>

**There are no specific mentions of a muggle ever becoming a werewolf**, and there's also **no mentions of a muggle exhibiting magical powers due to being bitten** though it does seem that it is possible.