# Is there a way to allow Muggles to live together with wizards without being Obliviated in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

Suppose I have many good friends living in Muggle society and I want to invite them to join the wonderful wizard world and share the secret of magic. However, due to the International Statute of Secrecy, the Muggle who witness the magic phenomenon will be Obliviated. Is there any way to bypass this?

For example, it seems that werewolves are considered as a part of wizard society. If I turn my friend into a werewolf (if he agreed, maybe I can ask Lupin for help), will he be accepted by wizard society? Or is there better way to turn a Muggle into a magic-being?

Comment: Believe it or not, there's quite a list of Muggles who know that Wizards exist. So one can invite muggles to wizarding events. Hermione's parents have visited Diagon Alley, I think even some muggle parents were there during the final event of the Triwizard tournament in Book 4.

Comment: Also, semi dupe of [Can a werewolf turn a muggle into another werewolf?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196810/if-a-muggle-is-to-turn-into-a-werewolf-would-they-be-able-to-learn-magic)

Comment: You can't give a Muggle magical powers, so they would never truly be a "magic-being". However, marrying a Muggle allows you to tell them about your being a witch or wizard, exposing them to the Wizarding world, so if you're committed enough you could tell at least one friend. No idea what happens if you divorce them, though; for safety reasons they may have the memories relating to magic removed.

Comment: damn...is it possible to marry more than one person under Wizard's law?@AnthonyGrist

Comment: @Harry As far as I'm aware that isn't directly addressed anywhere in canon. It was illegal in England before the International Statute of Secrecy, so it's possible that wizards do have similar laws against it.

Comment: Publish a series of internationally acclaimed and incredibly vivid books about some wizard kid and create a cult following for it; half of 'em'll actually believe it.

Comment: there are two totally different question here... 1) Can Muggles see magic and not be obliviated which is obviously a yes and 2) Can you turn a Muggle into a magic user...